# If $p$ a prime number $\mathbb{Z}^{\times}_p$ is always isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}_{p-1},+)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1127555/283262

someone stated: "If $p$ a prime number $\mathbb{Z}^{\times}_p$ is always isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}_{p-1},+)$"
What is this Theorem called? Where can i find it? How to proove it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can find it in every introductory Number Theory textbook ever published.

Comment: The multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314846/for-what-n-is-u-n-cyclic) is a post asking a slightly more general question.

Comment: @Arthur Thank you, this is very intresting

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa That comment makes it look much easier than it really is. It is nowhere near sufficient to note that they have the same order.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft true, but still it was a hint I think. it is indeed not sufficient

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft but you are right, it may be misleading. I will remove it :)

Comment: dont worry, im ok :)